# Why do rivers 'burst' their banks?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

We have had a lot of flooding in the UK in the last week or two, with reports, among other things, of rivers 'bursting their banks'.

The verb 'to burst' implies 'breaking or splitting as a result of internal pressure or puncturing' (ODE). But that is not what happens when a river floods. The water simply rises above the banks and floods the surrounding countryside.

So why do rivers 'burst' their banks?  What would be a more accurately descriptive way of saying it?

Comment: When the expression first arose, it seems that *"overflow"* and *"burst their banks"* do not appear to have been synonyms. From  [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=CMsHAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA5&dq=%22burst+their+banks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2DLLUsiwEqaysASgsoDADQ&ved=0CGYQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22burst%20their%20banks%22&f=false), 1817: ***The rivers Caldew, Eden, Peterill, Line, Irthing, &c. &c. have overflown or burst their banks.***

Comment: What do you mean 'better'? It works just fine for most people. What are your criteria for 'better'? Shorter? more formal? Less visually arresting? Why do people still 'hang up' their phone?

Comment: Looking at the uses of *burst its banks* in the late 18th and early 19th century, I believe there was a distinction then. If a river overflowed, it simply flooded the surrounding countryside. If it burst its banks, it created a new stream of rushing water (in addition to the old one) which could not just flood things, but could carry them away.

Comment: Consider also the metaphorical usage _burst out_ (in the sense of speaking). Nothing is actually broken.

Comment: "Breaking or splitting as a result of internal pressure or puncturing" is but ONE meaning of burst. People can burst into tears, doors can burst open, young lovers can be bursting with joy, cupboards can be bursting with food, sunshine can burst through the clouds, and a river can burst when [water rises above its sides and spreads over the surrounding area](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/burst).

Comment: @J.R. But those are metaphorical uses of 'burst'. 'Bursting with joy' conjures something pumped up to bursting point. But what happens when a river floods is not a metaphorical use. But I understand the distinction Peter seems to be making between a river simply flooding, and a situation where it creates a new stream. But I don't think that is the way the news people have been using 'river bursts its banks' in the last few days.

Comment: @ColinFine Yours is also a metaphorical use, as you say. If I 'burst out laughing', that is because it happens suddenly like something literally bursting.

Comment: @Mitch Well, people used to 'hang-up' the phone literally, and, dare I say it, it's a hangover from that. But the way rivers behave in flood has not changed since the earth began.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When dictionaries recognizes a definition of a word to mean "(for a river) to overflow", then why _shouldn't_ a journalist use that word in a headline or news story? The fact that the word happens to mean something else in other contexts doesn't change it's validity. It would be like asking "Why do they call it a heart _attack_, when _attack_ means when one army fights another?" Call the usage metaphorical if it makes you feel better. Moreover, you've answered your own question, in a way; if you don't like _burst_, what's wrong with _flood_?

Comment: @WS2: In current usage, I am fairly sure "burst its banks" is a synonym for overflowed. But I can see that metaphorically, it could have arisen from the image of a river bursting its banks and rampaging over the countryside, much like a wild animal could burst its cage and roam the countryside.

Comment: @J.R. It is worth looking at 'burst' in the OED. There are multiple examples of its use almost all of which borrow heavily from its primary meaning which is given as: 'To break suddenly, snap, crack, under violent pressure, strain, or concussion. Chiefly said of things possessing considerable capacity for resistance and breaking with loud noise...'
There is a reference to a river 'bursting' its banks, but based on a sole quotation from 1860. What happens when a river floods runs completely counter to an idea of 'bursting', that I regard it as a rogue usage. c.fwd.

Comment: @J.R. bfwd. I believe 'heart attack' is not analogous to the idea of a river 'bursting'. In that an h.a. is dangerous, something that happens suddenly, and an event to guard and take precaution against. 'Attack' seems an apt enough word to use. Incidentally the 1860 ref re rivers was 'a sub-glacial lake had burst its boundary' (Tyndall), perhaps not quite the same thing as the River Severn flooding the meadows at its banks. I am not entirely satisfied with 'flood', though it is much better than 'burst'. My problem is that I am not entirely clear where a river's 'bank' begins and ends.

Comment: @WS2 - RE: _My problem is that I am not entirely clear where a river's 'bank' begins and ends._ Oh, that's an easy one. The bank ends right where the river bursts. ;^)

Comment: @PeterShor What is a river bank? Is it merely the vertical part that contains the river, or does it extend horizontally onto the adjoining land? Assuming there is no raging torrent, how far on to the land does the water have to flow in order for the river to be said to have 'flooded its banks'? I have given up on bursting, I will never use the mad expression again.

Comment: In answer to Mitch's criticism, perhaps if you edit your last question to say: What would be a more accurate description? Then everybody would be happier :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA More accurately descriptive?

Comment: Not that, in some areas of the world, it's quite common for a river to literally "burst its banks", since either a natural or artificial embankment surrounds the river, and when this is over-topped the soil comprising the embankment will very rapidly erode away at the lowest spots, producing a gash in the embankment.

Comment: @WS2 - https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdNgMdOSEdq3EmNnhCYlfH7o67dsXcP6hzBv4LVyvqTFHoLveb, http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-H0CauNk0Rxc/UECe7gSa8wI/AAAAAAAAFKg/bMNdUAcfHDs/s1600/11502685-standard.jpg, http://s1.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20130610&t=2&i=739875955&w=&fh=&fw=&ll=700&pl=300&r=CBRE95915LK00

Comment: Many rivers now days are kept behind levees. When a levee breaks, the situation deteriorates quite rapidly as flowing water is very erosive. No doubt there are good videos of the process on the internet, hidden behind all the Led Zeppelin vids.

Comment: But of course, the use of the term to refer to a river that is simply overflowing is well-established:  [2 b :  to flood over <the river burst its banks>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burst).  A word means what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common term is US usage is **[overflow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/overflow?q=overflow)**

> (especially of a liquid) flow over the brim of a receptacle:
>
> [with object]: *the river overflowed its banks*

In many places, water is contained by dikes or levees and these *are* prone to **bursting**.  Theses are more often lakes or inland seas than rivers, but some broad rivers are contained by levees. See this [discussion](http://www.tulane.edu/~bfleury/envirobio/enviroweb/FloodControl.htm) of the Mississippi Levee System. Also a [discussion](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-06-10/hungary-contains-danube-flooding-as-german-levee-bursts.html) of the Danube bursting its levees in Germany.

In those cases, the river may well **burst** its banks (fracture the levees). However, this may or may not apply to the rivers of England.

Comment: No, the idiom (in the UK) does not imply that the banks have sustained lasting damage: they may have, but not necessarily.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes I agree. The main river in question recently has been the Severn, and as far as I know it always emerges from these floods in the same state it was before. But I think it's an important point that bib makes.

Comment: It doesn't just rise and then fall and everything is as it was before. A river bursting its banks does [a lot of damage](https://www.dw.com/en/climate-change-flooding-germany-dernau-rebuilding-homes/a-59640272). Debris and mud is everywhere. Buildings can be damaged or even destroyed if the waters are fast and high enough. The word "burst" seems quite natural.

Answer (score 1):

Might this be linked to the drainage of the English Fens? It was a project which was attempted on and off for centuries, but it involved the cutting of new channels ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fens#Early_modern_attempts_to_drain_the_Fens) says that the old and new Bedford rivers were two prime examples) with raised banks, to stop the water from pouring back over the reclaimed lands. This project was largely completed by 1820, a few years after Peter Shor's quote. In this context a burst bank would be different to an overflowing river, as the quote implies, and would be an accurate description of what has happened.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of the word 'burst' which is what the question asked.

Comment: While I don't agree with @Chenmunka, an answer with no more endorsement than 'Might it be ...' is not adequate on ELU.

Answer (score -1):

You are entirely right to question this usage.

It used to be that if a river "burst it's banks" it actually did damage to said banks that would need to be repaired. If the river level became higher than the banks it would be said that it had "over topped it's banks".

Unfortunately our journalists/ politicians have been misusing the term (because of hype/ignorance) for ages so it has become acceptable to use the term burst when no actual damage has been done to the river bank.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Bryn. You might consider improving this answer by citing sources for your opinions.